# Padding in a Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Pyspark dataframe(**Original Dataframe**) having below data(all columns have **string** datatype):

```
  id           Value
   1             103
   2             1504
   3              1
```

I need to create a new **modified dataframe** with **padding** in **value** column, so that length of this column should be **4 characters**. If length is less than 4 characters, then add 0's in data as shown below:

```
  id             Value
   1             0103
   2             1504
   3             0001
```

Can someone help me out? How can i achieve it using Pyspark dataframe? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if few of the columns also containing null value , then to add prefix to the column value, Please specify.

Answer (score 26):

You can use lpad from functions module,

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lpad
>>> df.select('id',lpad(df['value'],4,'0').alias('value')).show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1| 0103|
|  2| 1504|
|  3| 0001|
+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 9):

Using PySpark `lpad` function in conjunction with `withColumn`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
dfNew = dfOrigin.withColumn('Value', F.lpad(dfOrigin['Value'], 4, '0'))
```