# how to add leading zeroes to a pyspark dataframe column

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to add leading zeroes to a column in my pyspark dataframe

input :-

ID
123

Output expected:

000000000123

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Padding in a Pyspark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400829/padding-in-a-pyspark-dataframe)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is lpad function.
Left-pad the string column to width len with pad.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lpad
df.select(lpad(df.ID, 12, '0').alias('s')).collect()
```

Answer (score 14):

Use [`format_string`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.format_string) function to pad zeros in the beginning.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, format_string
df = spark.createDataFrame([('123',),('1234',)],['number',])
df.show()
+------+
|number|
+------+
|   123|
|  1234|
+------+
```

If the number is `string`, make sure to cast it into `integer`.

```
df = df.withColumn('number_padded', format_string("%012d", col('number').cast('int')))
df.show()
+------+-------------+
|number|number_padded|
+------+-------------+
|   123| 000000000123|
|  1234| 000000001234|
+------+-------------+
```

Comment: I applied this logic but a new column "number_padded" did not get created

Comment: I did exactly what you have mentioned but the new column is not formed

Comment: Well I moved to the next step , got the new column generated but that has all null values . Looks like the logic did not work.

Comment: It works for me on multiple pyspark versions. I don’t know why it doesn’t work for you.

Comment: This solutions works better and it is more robust. It should be the accepted answer

Comment: I prefer this solution because it preserves the original column