# extract hour from timestamp column in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using below functionality to extract hour from current_timestamp

```
F.hour(F.to_timestamp(F.current_timestamp(),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC'"))
```

This would return me as **5** the current hour

[image]

whereas I want the result as **05**

Any solution to this would be helpfull

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add leading zeroes to a pyspark dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959643/how-to-add-leading-zeroes-to-a-pyspark-dataframe-column)

Comment: @Luuk I would not like to add zeros to all the rows if the hour is in single digit then only would like to have zeroes to it

Comment: use: `format_string("%02d", hour)` , see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57960165/724039

Comment: @Luuk this would add formatting to all rows right. ex:if the hour is 13 i don't want to prefix 0 to it only if hour ranges from 1-9 would like to have it

Comment: it should work fine. %02d does not mean that it is going to add zero to every number, but will ensure that number has at least 2 digits, and if it is shorter this function going to add leading zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the lpad function in pyspark to add add 0 only when you have single digits in that column:

```
df.withColumn("hour", F.lpad(F.hour(F.to_timestamp(F.current_timestamp(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC'")), 2, "0"))
```